# Average multiple values from multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel

I need to calculate the average from the percentages shown in the picture below but I need to ignore the 0s. 
So, I need the average of the first row of percentages, precisely cells H1, K1 and N1, but because K1 is a 0 I will not include it. So the first average is 100%.

I know about averageif but I cant make it work, and I do not think it would in this case

[image]

Comment: I don not understand where you are trying to get

Answer (score 1):

```
=IFERROR((H1+K1+N1)/((H1>0)+(K1>0)+(N1>0)),0)
```

Comment: @pnuts yes in all three examples the answer would be 100%, so the easy answer is `=1`